# Si hace click 3 veces, ha de desactivarse botón - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, script, botón, dom

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando de 3 veces en Añadir, el boton se desactive?

```
 <button id='botones' type='submit' name='enviar'>Añadir</button>
            <script>
            var cantidad=document.getElementById("botones")
            cantidad.addEventListener("onclick",()=>{
              if(cantidad.value>3){
                document.getElementById("botones").disabled=true
              }
            })
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- El evento que estas escuchando es incorrecto deberías estar escuchando el evento `click`.

  - Para controlar la cantidad de veces que se le da click al botón es necesario crear una variable externa para llevar el contador de clicks.

Quedaria algo asi.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id='botones'
            type='submit'
            name='enviar'>Añadir</button>
    <script>
        var boton = document.getElementById("botones")
        var cantidad = 0;
        boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (cantidad >= 2) {
                boton.disabled = true
            }
            cantidad = cantidad + 1;
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```